# local user name disallowed chars

Tags: c#, .net, path, system-administration

currently if I try to add local user "jim,bob" to a Windows 7 system, as expected, the following error dialog is shown displaying all the illegal chars for a user name. Is there a quick .net method to call which returns the same chars? E.g.

```
Path.GetInvalidPathChars();
```

returns all the invalid path chars. Is there a similar method out there for user names?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars() - ?

**User Name Policies** from http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722458.aspx

A key policy you'll need to set is the naming scheme for accounts. In Windows NT, user names must follow these rules:

Local user names must be unique on a workstation.

Global user names must be unique throughout a domain.

User names must be no more than 20 characters in length.

User names cannot contain certain characters. Invalid characters include:

" / \ [ ] : ; | = , + * ? < >

User names can contain all other special characters, including spaces, periods, dashes, and underscores. But it's generally not a good idea to use spaces in account names. On some non-Windows NT systems, such as UNIX, spaces aren't valid in user names and the user may have difficulty accessing these systems.

Comment: And the character @ ?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is this:

`Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()`

Look at this for more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getinvalidfilenamechars.aspx

Comment: He mentions `Path.GetInvalidPathChars()` in his question, so I'm pretty sure he doesn't need a link to it.

Comment: @M.Babcock Umm, `Path.GetInvalidPathChars() ` and `Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()` are different..

Comment: And neither one of them do what he is asking for.